# Multiple Loops In Tabs Only Displaying First Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, tabs

I've browsed all the other questions that could be related to this and still can't find the answer. My code is only displaying the results of the loop in the first tab, but won't show it in the second tab. Can't figure out why. See code below:

```
<div class="tab-panels">
    <div class="panel entry-content active" id="tab_all-lines">
        <!-- Full Menu -->
        <?php
        $loop = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'featured_item', 
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'ASC',
            )
        );?>
        <ul id="menu-manufacturers-all-lines" class="menu">
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-featured_item">
                <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>"><? the_title();?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </ul>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="panel entry-content" id="tab_lines-we-stock">
        <!-- Filter Menu -->
        <?php
        $loop_stock = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'featured_item',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'category_name' => 'lines-we-stock',
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            )
        );?>
        <ul id="menu-manufacturers-all-lines" class="menu">
            <?php while ( $loop_stock->have_posts() ) : $loop_stock->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-featured_item">
                <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>"><? the_title();?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </ul>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you check the html output of the code in the browser?

Comment: Yes, not sure why this wouldn't work. Anyone spot anything wrong with my code?